# How to set Favicon in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, favicon

I know this is a stupid question, but I can't find the answer anywhere.  If I'm using Codeigniter, where do I save my favicon file so that it will pop up in the browser?  Or is there a config option in the files that I haven't been able to find yet? This is driving me crazy!

Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It depends on your organization. I usually put the favicon.gif file in the web root folder, so the URL would be `yourdomain.com/favicon.gif`

Then you have to add the following line of code into your HTML `<head>`:

```
<link rel="icon" href="<?=base_url()?>/favicon.gif" type="image/gif">
```

Assuming that the URL Helper is loaded in CodeIgniter. You can load it via `$this->load->helper('url');` or add it into the autoload helper array in your config folder.

Comment: darn... beat me to it!

You could just make the link /favicon.gif if it's in the site root, instead of calling the helper.

Comment: Of course! But since I am running CodeIgniter applications on a local server for testing and publish them when finished, I want them to be as dynamic as possible so publishing is no pain.

Comment: Worked like a charm, of course.  I've designed them before, but never had to include a link -- always get them auto-detected by browser somehow.  Thanks!!

Comment: Glad to hear! :)

Some browsers (e.g. Safari) try to auto-detect a favicon like you said.

For example, if you visit www.typolexikon.de Safari tries to load www.typolexikon.de/favicon.ico which returns a 404 page about 10 times as large as a favicon would be.

Comment: @DavidC. I've tried this but it doesn't seem to work for me. When I inspect the page source and try and open the link to the favicon I get a 404. Could this be a config problem? The favicon shows up on Firefox if the icon isn't at the document root.

Comment: @Paulie Put the favicon somewhere where it can be accessed and change the path inside the code to `<?=base_url()?>/path/to/favicon.gif`. Or investigate why the favicon can't be accessed when you put it inside the document root.

Answer (score 3):

You could load the **HTML helper** and use `<?php echo link_tag('favicon.ico', 'shortcut icon', 'image/ico'); ?>` on the `<head>` html tag.
More information in http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/html_helper.html#link_tag

Answer (score 2):

I have used this in my code and its working fine

```
<pre>
<link rel="icon" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>favicon.ico" type="image/gif">
</pre>
```

Comment: This worked for me. I am using CodeIgniter 4. I put the favicon.ico in the root of "public" dir.