# Favicon not displayed

Tags: codeigniter, favicon

I've tried including the favicon in different ways.

```
<link rel="icon" href="<?=base_url()?>favicon.ico">

<link href="favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />

<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/codeigniter/favicon.ico">
```

The favicon dosen't show up and when I inspect the page source and navigate to the favicon I get a 404. Am I missing some sort of configuration with codeigniter?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set Favicon in Codeigniter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3478720/how-to-set-favicon-in-codeigniter)

Comment: I've had a look at that question and the answers don't solve my problem.

Comment: have you cleared your browser cache ? Try other browsers as well

Comment: tried both with no luck.

Comment: <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="<?php echo base_url()."images/icon2.ico"?>">

Comment: "when I inspect the page source and navigate to the favicon I get a 404", sounds like your url to the favicon might be wrong, put it on root of your hosting, try to open it in browser, if that works then it's just your url's

Comment: and btw this is what we use <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="codeigniter/favicon.ico">
```

all browsers should work without setting the type as image/x-icon with the exception of IE6 and 7, which look for the type.

The icon might also only show up when on a webhost, and not when run locally.

Answer (score 0):

Set base_url properly first...then try this..

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href=<?php echo base_url()."static/images/favicon.ico"?>>
```

Comment: Instead of just posting a one-liner of code, you should explain a little bit your answer.

Comment: As per my understanding Chrome requires the .ico file to be at the root folder and this would not be suitable for chrome.

Comment: I have tested it on chrome

Comment: It works on Firefox but not on Google Chrome. I have also done a hard referesh and cleared the cache but the .ico file does not show up on Chrome.

Comment: where is your ico file

Comment: I have placed it here /codeigniter/static/images/favicon.ico and changed the path accordingly. Does it have to be in a folder images?

Comment: <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="<?php echo base_url()."static/images/favicon.ico"?>">

Comment: I have upvoted you answer since it helped me. Thanks a lot.