# Codeigniter: Favicon icon is not loading, checked in all browser

Tags: codeigniter-3

Problem: Favicon Icon is not loading.

I have a folder 'Assets' in the root directory of codeigniter framework.
Assets/images/favicon.png is the path for the favicon icon image. 
The image is present at the above mentioned location.
Controller code:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class homeController extends CI_Controller {
    public function index()
    {   
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->view('header');
        }
}
```

View: header.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>My-site</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="<?php base_url();?>assets/images/favicon.png" type="image/png">


</head>
```

But the image is not coming.

I tried: [How to set Favicon in Codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3478720/how-to-set-favicon-in-codeigniter)
i.e moved the favicon.png in the root folder. But still it is not working.

I tried below as well:
In controller

```
$this->load->helper('html');
```

In view:

```
<?php echo link_tag('favicon.ico', 'shortcut icon', 'image/ico');?>
```

still it is not working.

Can anyone please help me out with this??

Answer (score 0):

View source of your page in browser and check if the link tag of favicon is present . Check if favicon image path is proper and try favicon url in browser .

Comment: Hello @Sachin, I tried this earlier, In console the link in shown and if i hit the url in the browser then the image is also shown.. but in the title bar it is not coming.
"https://localhost/my-project/assets/images/favicon.png" - This is the link of the image